# Is there a better way to achieve this using Perl?

Tags: perl, environment-variables

I am writing a Perl script which does this :

1. Reads the values of the environment variables `a` to `z` in a loop.
2. Depending on the value of the environment variables, generates a **result** file similar to

   ```
   a - 1,2,3,4
   b - a,b,c
   c - $234.34,$123.12
   keyword1 %a%
   keyword2 %b%
   keyword3 %c%
   ```

   The point to note is that all the **declarations** have to come before the **usages**.
3. The problem is that for example I read `a`, and generate this **result** file

   ```
   a - 1,2,3,4
   keyword3 %c%
   ```

   Now when I read `b` , I need the **result** file to look like this

   ```
   a - 1,2,3,4
   b - a,b,c
   keyword1 %a%
   keyword2 %b%
   ```

How should I do this using Perl?

One way I can think of is to  generate two different files - one with the **declarations** and other with the **usages**, and then concatenate the files at the end of execution of the script.

Is there a better way?

Comment: What would the purpose of this be -- how is it useful? What is the consumer of this script's output?

Comment: Can you add more info about what you're trying to do? It's not completely clear what actions you want to take. What if a variable is unset? What do you want to do with any given one based on the setting?

Comment: @Ether: This formatted output is finally parsed by yet another script that does some further work.

Comment: Better than what? It doesn't seem like you showed us the current way you're doing things.

Comment: @Daenyth: I shall be handling all the error cases (variable unset etc.) What I want to know is that how can I progressively generate the output file?

Comment: @rafl: Better than generating two different files and concatenating. I am not sure why that was not clear.

Comment: @Lazer: *What problem are you trying to solve*. You still haven't told us what you're *actually* trying to do. Why do you need them printed in this format? Once you read them, what do you want to do? What have you tried and why didn't it work? Do you not understand the syntax for doing this in perl? Or is it a logic issue?

Comment: I have updated the question, hope I make myself clear now.

Comment: @Daenyth: The problem is only generating the output file. I think, it does not add to the question at all what the use is. Anyways, please see the updated question.

Comment: @Lazer: This is not any more clear at all. What do you mean by "declarations"? Do you mean a list of variables which are defined and a list of variables which are not defined?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No need for separate files. Accumulate the declarations and usages in two different array variables, `@declarations` and `@usages`. After you've read all your environment variables and determined the contents of the two arrays, print them:

```
say for @declarations;
say for @usages;
```

You might even be able to omit the first array. Once you figure out what a declaration should be, print it out immediately. You only need to accumulate the usages until you know there will be no more declarations.

Comment: Thanks @Rob, arrays are a good choice, and are definitely better than having to create two separate files and concatenating.

Comment: @Lazer: I think this was the point of all the commenters above -- what is the purpose of the output -- why output to files at all?

Comment: @Ether, evidently, Lazer's script is generating code to be executed later by some other interpreter. I don't see why there's so much resistance to the idea of having a Perl script whose purpose is to create a file.

Comment: having a script create a file which is just going to be processed again by another script implies that the two scripts could be combined.

Answer (score 1):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @keys = sort keys %ENV;
print "$_ - $ENV{$_}\n" foreach @keys;
my $kwcnt = 1;
print "keyword${ \( $kwcnt++ ) } \%$_\%\n" foreach @keys;
```

I sort the keys once, and run through them twice.